# How to get a CD out?

Tags: chevrolet, audio, silverado

I just put a new head unit in my '06 Chevy Silverado pick-up. I did the unthinkable of leaving a CD in the unit before I pulled it (yah, got a little excited to get the new head unit installed!). Is there a simple way to get the CD's out of the head unit without destroying it? For reference, this is what the head unit looks like:

[image]

This one is just an image I pulled from Google. Obviously since this one is not installed, yet powered up, there has to be a way to do this. Are there pins in the back you can apply power which would power up the unit? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some searching on the Interwebz and found this wiring breakout of the plug which goes into the back side of the stock head unit:

[image]

Here is an image of the socket in the back of the head unit:

[image]

You cannot tell it in this image, but at the base near the pins the two rows are lettered (A & B) and each pin along the A row is numbered. From this, I took a small 12vdc battery I have (which I keep around for such an occasion), took some alligator clips and attached the positive lead to B1 & B2 at the same time (I *believe* you need to do this, as both would have power when the ignition is turned on) and the negative lead to A12. I heard the head unit shuffle the CD inside, so I turned the unit over and pressed the "CD Eject" button, which pushed the CD out for me.

Please note ... if you plug in the power backwards, expect something to get fried. For me, one of the two alligator clipped leads basically melted in two. I then changed out the polarity of the clips (after obtaining a new lead, lol) and it worked like a charm. I had misread the positioning prior to realizing the socket was labeled as to which pin was what. Happens to the best of us.